# How exactly do Helmets work in Apex Legend?

Tags: apex-legends

Is it percentage damage reduction? Life points, similar to body armor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They essentially reduce bonus headshot damage, with higher tiers having more of a reduction.

White: **30%** Reduction

Blue: **40%** Reduction

Purple/Gold: **50%** Reduction

They also do no break like shields from armour does.

Source: [Chad Armstrong, Designer at Respawn](http://web.archive.org/web/20190207233921/https:/twitter.com/ShishkaTweets/status/1093591170091892736)

Comment: It's worth noting that Legendary (Gold) gear has the same effects as Epic (Purple) plus a bonus effect.  The Gold helmet charges your tactical (Q) and ultimate (Z) abilities faster than normal.

Comment: @Buns Glazing Absolutely, this should be added into the answer to make it more complete.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new answer recently. Reddit user “TheChessur” worked out that actually the damage reduction applies to total damage; and the reductions themselves are much smaller than expected, at 10%/20%/25%.

- A headshot with a Wingman would deal 45 body shot damage, plus 45
  bonus headshot damage, for a total of 90.
- If you headshot an enemy with a White Helmet, the game’s description would have you believe you deal 45 + (0.7*45) = 77 damage.
- But in fact, the headshot deals (0.9*90) = 81 damage.

Source:

1. https://www.rockpapershotgun.com/2019/03/18/apex-legends-armor-and-gear-guide-helmet-backpack-knockdown-shield-body-shield/
2. https://www.reddit.com/r/apexlegends/comments/aqzism/skullpiercer_rifling_helmets_explained/